# Guessing a number and printing it if it is within 10

Tags: python, random

Basically I have a program that lets the user make a guess between 1 and 1000. I have most of the code, but the thing I'm stuck on is if the user guess is within a 10-point difference of the number generated but higher than the number generated, print “Getting warm but still high!
 And vice versa if the user guess is within a 10 point difference of the number generated but lower than the number generated, then give the print “Getting warm but still Low!”

Here's my code

```
import random
number=random.randint(1,1000)
count=1
guess= eval(input("Enter your guess between 1 and 1000 "))

while guess !=number:
 count+=1

 if guess > number:
  print("Too high!")
 elif guess < number:
  print("Too low!")

 guess = eval(input("Try again "))

print("You rock! You guessed the number in" , count , "tries!")
```

Comment: Can you please add the code language as a label?

Comment: Looks like python. :)

Comment: You should consider using `int()` instead of `eval()`; it makes your purpose more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Compute the difference between the number and guess.

```
diff = guess - number

if diff < -10:
    print("Much too low!")
elif diff > 10:
    print("Much too high!")
elif diff < 0:
    print("Getting warm but still low!")
elif diff > 0:
    print("Getting warm but still high!")
else:
    print("Correct!")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the steps you like

```
 if guess > number + 10:
  print("Too high!")
 elif guess < number - 10:
  print("Too low!")
 elif guess > number:
  print("Getting warm but still high!")
 elif guess < number:
  print("Getting warm but still Low!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if guess+10 >= number and guess < number:
    print("warm but low!")

if guess > target and guess-10 <= number:
    print("warm but high!")
```